# Determining Cause of "Uncaught Error" in ECharts Line Animation Script During Data Swap

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm trying to update this eCharts with my own data and encountered a vague error that I cannot decipher to debug.

```
echarts.min.js:45 Uncaught Error
    at vo (echarts.min.js:45:7325)
    at Object.prepareGetValue (echarts.min.js:45:901430)
    at echarts.min.js:45:900501
    at gG (echarts.min.js:45:900842)
    at echarts.min.js:45:900983
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at z (echarts.min.js:35:5289)
    at yG (echarts.min.js:45:900959)
    at gG (echarts.min.js:45:900327)
    at new t (echarts.min.js:45:901100)
```

This is the working code without my changes: https://codepen.io/kml-projects/pen/poxzazM

This is the broken code where I've attempted to swap "json" data with "nu_data": https://codepen.io/kml-projects/pen/bGmbaXQ

The data structures are similar, but my new data is a array of 3 vs. 4

The code below is reading and filtering the lists, and my attempts to update it for "nu_data" sample might be the problem.

```
 const countries = [
    'Fourth',
    'Third',
    'Second',
    'Top'
  ];
  const datasetWithFilters = [];
  const seriesList = [];
  echarts.util.each(countries, function (country) {
    var datasetId = 'dataset_' + country;
    datasetWithFilters.push({
      id: datasetId,
      fromDatasetId: 'dataset_raw',
      transform: {
        type: 'filter',
        config: {
          and: [
            { dimension: 'Year', gte: 1950 },
            { dimension: 'Quartile', '=': country }
          ]
        }
      }
    });
    seriesList.push({
      type: 'line',
      datasetId: datasetId,
      showSymbol: false,
      name: country,
      endLabel: {
        show: true,
        formatter: function (params) {
          return params.value[1] + ': ' + params.value[0];
        }
      },
      labelLayout: {
        moveOverlap: 'shiftY'
      },
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      encode: {
        x: 'Year',
        y: 'Income',
        label: ['Quartile', 'Income'],
        itemName: 'Year',
        tooltip: ['Income']
      }
    });
  });
```

Any guidance appreciated, thanks for your time.

TRIED:

Updating "json" var data w/ "nu_data"

Updated const "countries" for the filter statement

Swapped "Country" for "Quartile" in code

EXPECTED: Data to animate like example or an error that would describe the issue with the data / format

Answer (score 0):

Dataset was updated where indicated in the code below instead of just in the "run" statement

So long as the data array of arrays has a "headers" array, it will work

```
option = {
    animationDuration: 10000,
    dataset: [
      {
        id: 'dataset_raw',
        source: **UPDATE HERE***
      },
      ...datasetWithFilters
    ],
    title: {
      text: 'Income of Germany and France since 1950'
    },
    tooltip: {
      order: 'valueDesc',
      trigger: 'axis'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      nameLocation: 'middle'
    },
    yAxis: {
      name: 'Income'
    },
    grid: {
      right: 140
    },
    series: seriesList
  };
  myChart.setOption(option);
}
```